# slideUP div behind the footer with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div image of 235px of height, and my footer have only 80px of height, i need slide up this div from behind of footer, how i can do it? i need that div behind slide up when click in a link

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/HqmUk/

because the div behind footer break the layout

```
<div class="footer"></div><!-- footer of 80px -->
<div class="sitemap"></div><!-- div behind of 235px of height -->
```

Comment: slideup on what??by default?or when you click something?

Comment: OH!...im sorry, i forgot this detail, when click only

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/HqmUk/2/) code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".footer").click(function(){
      //when you click on footer,third div will sliding up
        $(".slideup").slideUp();
    })
});
</script>
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: but, and about the div behind the footer, i want that this div slideup, not the footer, the footer must be static.